# Multiselect dropdown where selected values cannot be deselected on edit?

Tags: user-expectation, design-patterns, dropdown, drop-down-list

I'm trying to find examples of a multi-select dropdown where once the form is saved/submitted, the selected values cannot be removed but, new values can be added.

Currently, I've designed it to work as follows:
[image]

Are there are examples of dropdowns which work with similar constraints? How are such constraints handled?

Answer (score 3):

I do not have an example. But in your solution it seems unclear why I can remove some selected items but not others. This brings me to the following solution:

Place the previously submitted values outside the dropdown. You can even label them so it is clear that they are submitted already. In the dropdown you place only the values still available. So the behaviour of the dropdown is always the same. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks and sorry if it was confusing, but what I meant was, the drop down is only additive. i.e, once some values have been selected and the form submitted, those values cannot be removed on edit, however, the remaining values can be added as usual during edit.  I think your solution works good but would it not lead to clutter if there are say, 20+ values selected?

Comment: @AshwinNepal If there is a selection you have to show them anyway. Otherwise the users would not know what they selected before. The more items selected the more true this is. The wireframes should only give an idea. You certainly have to be aware of the possibility of having many items selected when developing the visual design.